# How to get current location from GPS and set it into FlutterGoogleMap?

Tags: flutter, dart, google-maps-api-3, geolocation, google-maps-flutter

I want to load my google maps on flutter app to my current location.

the code i used is..

```
late LatLng _center;
  late Position currentLocation;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserLocation();
  }

  Future<Position> locateUser() async {
    return Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
        desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
  }

  getUserLocation() async {
    currentLocation = await locateUser();
    setState(() {
      _center = LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
    });
    print('center $_center');
  }
  static const CameraPosition _MyPostn = CameraPosition(
    target:_center,
    zoom: 14.4746,
  );
```

But I'm getting error as
[image]

What am I doing wrong here?

I did search other similar questions but didn't find any solution.

Answer (score 1):

You need location permission to access the GPS location. Assuming you have taken care of the permission(if not, please check the link below)

[geolocator 9.0.2](https://pub.dev/packages/geolocator)

You could you try like this

define _MyPostn as late.

Initialise _MyPostn once you get _center.

```
late LatLng _center;
late Position currentLocation;
late CameraPosition _MyPostn;
bool isLoading = true;

@override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    getUserLocation();
}

Future<Position> locateUser() async {
    return Geolocator.getCurrentPosition(
    desiredAccuracy: LocationAccuracy.high);
}

getUserLocation() async {
    currentLocation = await locateUser();
    setState(() {
      _center = LatLng(currentLocation.latitude, currentLocation.longitude);
    });
    print('center $_center');
    _MyPostn = CameraPosition(target:_center, zoom: 14.4746,);
    isLoading = false;
}
```

Comment: when running the app, it shows an error screen for a couple seconds and then loads the map. The error screen showed "LateInitializationError : Field _MyPostn575457168 has not been initialized."

Comment: You could manage this error screen by adding a conditional statement in the widget tree and show a circularProgessIndicator until the variable _MyPostn is initialised

Comment: Cool. what should the condition be?

Comment: check the modified code, added isLoading variable.
Inside Scaffold you may check the variable like 

body: 
          isLoading
              ? const Center(
                  child: CircularProgressIndicator(),
                )
              :  FinalWidgetToDisplay(),